# How to increase or decrease a progress bar width within given time with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> I'm making a typing [game](http://shovon.net/projects/js/sc/), there is a 1-second interval function in my
>   game already but I need something animated in UI. It will visually
>   show the user how the time is running out.

**In this code, I wanted to increase the progress bar from 0% to 100% in 7 seconds. Though I want decrease actually**

> How can I do this with pure javascript?

**Timing is Important here, The whole decrease/increase process should be done within my given time**

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
  // i want it to be done in 7 seconds
  var time = 7000;
  function frame() {
    if (width >= time) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = (100*width)/time + '%'; 
      elem.innerHTML = Math.round((100*width)/time)  + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">0%</div>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="move()">Start</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean you want to decrease the bar?

Comment: yes i want to decrease the bar

Comment: Not sure I get where the trouble is.  To have it decrease just do `elem.style.width = 100 - ((100*width)/time) + '%';`

Comment: I want the whole decrease process will happen in 7 seconds

Comment: Suggestion: I think changing the progress bars' text from percentages to seconds (and tenths of seconds) would be more meaningful to the user. E.g. `4.5 s`.

Comment: @Daan Yes, you are right. I will do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using `requestAnimationFrame` first.  Next, use a timer instead of counting how many times it is called.  I made a few minor adjustments (you can call it with a different number to have a different delay).

RAF docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

```js
function move(delay) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var end = Date.now() + delay;
  var frame = () => {
    var timeleft = Math.max(0, end - Date.now());
    elem.style.width = (100*timeleft)/delay + '%'; 
    elem.innerHTML = (timeleft/1000).toFixed(1)  + 's';
    if (timeleft === 0) return;
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  };
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">7.0s</div>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="move(7000)">Start</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine, thank you.
Can you please edit it decrease from 100% to 0% and change the progress bars' text from percentages to seconds.

Comment: Changed to seconds (with 1 decimal) and made it decrease.

Comment: Yes, Everything is fine, Thank you for your help @Goblinlord

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
  // i want it to be done in 7 seconds
  var time = 7000;
  function frame() {
    if (width >= time) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = 100-(100*width)/time + '%'; 
      elem.innerHTML = 100-Math.round((100*width)/time)  + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">100%</div>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="move()">Start</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want the whole decrease process will happen in 7 seconds

Comment: ah... the timing... that is what you need.